# ubuntu add c++ libraries

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, installation

I would like to install boost.iostreams library. I read on their [website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html), i may not do good things because this is not working.
So i try to install [bio++ package](http://biopp.univ-montp2.fr/wiki/index.php/Installation).

I add to my software manager the new sources. In command line I do this :

```
wget http://biopp.univ-montp2.fr/repos/apt/conf/biopp.gpg.key
sudo apt-key add biopp.gpg.key
```

But I am not sure to be in the good directory to do this. Where do I have to go ?

In general, how can i install a package or a library ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install <package>`

Comment: I already try this but I don't find the package name. I try "boost", "bio++", and "biopp"...

Comment: Their site sais: "Bio++ 2.1 packages (libbpp-core, libbpp-seq, etc.) are available in the Ubuntu and Debian standard repositories"... so I'd type sudo apt-get install libbpp- ... and hit tab... it will list the known packages that start with that.

Comment: BTW... not sure about the relationship between boost.iostream and this bio++....

Comment: I thought that if I install bio++ then boost.iostreams will be install. But I do not install the both

Comment: my collegue give me the answer ! sudo apt-get install libboost-dev